# Get web-mode to ignore file extension and racket-mode to honor it

Tags: web-mode, prelude, config

I use both **web-mode** and **racket-mode** often. I am also using Pollen, a Racket language for processing text. Pollen uses compound file extensions like:

```
pynchon.html.pm
stephenson.css.pp
wallace.html.pmd
```

The relevant extensions are `pm`, `pmd` and `pp`.

**web-mode** grabs onto these file extensions due the `css` and `html` portions on the extension. I would like it to stop doing that. I would like these files to be opened in **racket-mode**.

This is what I have tried so far in my `default.el` file (I am using **prelude**):

```
;; web-mode
(require 'web-mode)
(defun my-web-mode-hook ()
  "Hooks for Web mode."
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.p[mp]\\'" ignore t))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pmd\\'" ignore t)))
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook 'my-web-mode-hook)

;; racket-mode
(require 'racket-mode)
(defun racket-mode-hook ()
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.p[mp]\\'" . racket-mode))
  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.pmd\\'" . racket-mode)))

(add-hook 'racket-mode-hook 'racket-mode-hook)
```

Unfortunately my pollen files with an `html` extension (ex: `pynchon.html.pm`) still open in **html-mode** and my pollen files with a `pp` extension open in **puppet-mode**.

Answer (score 1):

Welp, managed to solved it.

I removed the relevant lines from `my-web-mode-hook` and added the following outside of the `racket-mode-hook` function:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.p[pmd]+\\'" . racket-mode))
```

My files are now opening in **racket-mode**.

Answer (score 0):

We can, in addition to just making sure that your racket files open up properly, make sure that files that end in `.html.anythingelse` also don't open up in html mode.

The default regexp that determines whether a file is opened in `html-mode` is:

```
"\\.[sx]?html?\\(\\.[a-zA-Z_]+\\)?\\'"
```

So, a filename that contains `.html` (or `.shtml`, or `.xhtml`) followed by either nothing, or a single period, then some more stuff. But really, we want to make sure the filename *ends* with `.html`.

So let's do that. But first, remove the old one from the list:

```
(require 'cl)
(setq auto-mode-alist
      (cl-remove-if (lambda (ele)
                      (equal ele
                             '("\\.[sx]?html?\\(\\.[a-zA-Z_]+\\)?\\'"
                               . html-mode)))
                    auto-mode-alist))
```

And now we can add a new regex matcher that makes sure we're matching at the *end* of the name:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[sx]?html?$" . html-mode))
```

And now, if you try to open `whatever.html`, it'll open in HTML mode as before, but if you try to open `whatever.html.pm`, it'll open in racket-mode.